# Expresso Store: Stock Control for Product Variations

Tags: expresso-store, shopping-cart, out-of-stock

Just wondering if there is scope to have stock control ability on product variations.

Useful for a scenario like mag wheels for cars:

Simmons Xtreme Chrome Mag (example model)
 - 17" (3 available)
 - 18" (2 available)
 - 19" (7 available)

Cheers.
=)

Answer (score 2):

If you add a product and choose Variation you can choose to control stock for each variant. 
I have attached a screenshot of an example:

[image]

Comment: Awesome man...thank you for showing me this, I didn't know there was stock control on variations in the back end, I pretty much assumed there wasn't after a quick look. I will be sure to check for your plugin as that will come in handy no doubt. I will be starting a site which could use all this in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're referring to displaying on the fronted, not creating in the backend? Store currently doesn't allow you to output the stock levels for modifier options. I've written a plugin that allows you to do just that for multiple modifiers and options, it's called Store Options and will be released on Devot-ee.com within the next couple of weeks, but if you want a copy of it prior to that drop me an email. peter@peteralewis.com

Comment: You can use the dynamic CSS classes to show stock levels on the front end <span class="store_product_stock"></span> would show the stock level after you have selected a particular SKU

Comment: Yep, but from Trents' description I assumed he wanted a list not specifically showing individual stock after selecting option.

Comment: @PeterLewis I don't see Store Options on Devot-ee.com

Comment: https://github.com/peteralewis/store_options